# When are "deleted" tsfiles droppen in IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

when I delete a timeseries in IoTDB (0.13.0) with `DELETE TIMESERIES xxx` I cant query it anymore but I realized that the tsfiles are still stored and also a call to `MERGE` or `FLUSH` didnt clean them up.

So my question is, when are these tsfiles cleaned up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when user deletes some data, we just store a .mods file in related tsfiles. The .mods file will be remove after its related tsfile is compacted.
However, not all files need to be compacted, currently, we just do two compaction when (1) the tsfiles are small (2) the tsfiles are in the unsequence folder.

So, if a tsfile is large enough in sequence folder, we will not compact it, thus the .mods file will exist.

A TsFile-Settle tool is developed to rewrite a tsfile with mods in 0.13.0, but this need to be called manually. We will later think about how to integrate this into the compaction.

Comment: Thanks, so as of now they would be kept by the server?

Comment: Hi, yes. if a tsfile is large enough in sequence folder, the .mods file will exist now.